# How to insert image before many circles in Raphael

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

Here is a [running demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/gV2Ac/2/) showing the issue.

I am trying to change a background image of Raphael Paper which has plotted some dots (circles) from an existing array like this:

```
var coords = [
               [ 218.5149144 , 215.5990218 ],
               [ 705.5489248 , 587.6430517 ],
               [ 297.0329404 , 360.5962827 ],
               [ 235.9094655 , 372.6983263 ],
               [ 400.8240728 , 486.9852929 ]
              ];

for(var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++){
    (function() {
                var circle; 
                circle = map.circle(coords[i][0], coords[i][1], 6);
                circle.toFront();
                circle.attr({
                             fill: '#f63832',
                             translation: "4,4",
                             stroke: '#FFF',
                            'stroke-width': 2,
                             opacity: 1,
                             });
    circle.hover(
                 function () {
                              circle.animate({
                                              fill: 'red',
                                              opacity: .6,
                                              r: 8,
                                             'stroke-width': 2.5
                                              }, 300)
                 }, function () {
                               circle.animate({
                                              fill: '#f63832',
                                              opacity: 1,
                                             'stroke-width': 2,
                                              r: 6
                                              }, 300)
                        }    );
                 })();
 };

$("#change").on("click",function(){
    image2.animate({ opacity: 0}, 500, mina.easein, function(){image2.remove();
                  image2  = map.image('http://localhost:8888/Ep/img/image2.png', -100, 0, 794, 680).insertBefore( circle ).animate({ opacity: 1, x: 0 }, 500, mina.easeout) ;                  
 });

});
```

Now I have issue in the `.insertBefore( circle )` part which doesn't recognize the circle object and I am getting following error on console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: circle is not defined

So I decided to remove `var circle;` from inside of the Loop and declared it globally which fixed the `.insertBefore( circle )` issue, but in this case I am losing hover function capability of the dots. How can I fix this issue?

### Update

I forgot to mention that removing the `var circle;`  from the loop and declaring it at the top of script insert the image only after last plotted dot.

Comment: You have 4 circles, so you need to think about what you are trying to actually do. One solution could be to have a group, put the circles in a group and insertBefore the group. Or store the first circle, and inserting before the first circle would probably be sufficient.

Comment: Have a read of the docs for the group element here http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Paper.g and you can 'g.add(circle)' or similar. Make sure you initialise the group variable outside the loop, and then add to them inside the loop.

Comment: My mistake, for some reason I was thinking you were using Snap which uses g. As you are using Raphael, you can store elements in a set and push an element onto it. http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Set

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54148/discussion-between-mona-coder-and-ian).

Comment: Can you please take a look at this demo http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/gV2Ac/5/
I used the set() but not sure that I am using it correctly!